# bitnami Review Board The Python module "subvertpy" is not installed when adding repository

Tags: python, review-board

bitnami  Review Board   The Python module "subvertpy" is not installed when adding repository

The Python module "subvertpy" is not installed. You may need to restart the server after installing it.

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: I tried Manually install subvertpy by pip and easy install but all failed. I donot know how to fix this issue~

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to beening some error on bitnami ReivewCode 4.04, I try a lower verion on

bitnami-reviewboard-3.0.9-1-linux-debian-9-x86_64.ovam,and problem solved!!